# [AWS Cognito]: How to send Reset Password one-click link instead of verification code

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-cognito, forgot-password

Using the [ForgotPassword API of AWS Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html), we can send a verification code to the end-users. How can we send a one-click Reset password link to the end user instead of this verification code?

Comment: Have you ever solved this, I want this feature too.

Comment: No. After going through the Cognito docs, it looks like it is not supported as of now.